# About the definition of convergence of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, definition

What will happen if the choice of $N$ in the definition of convergence doesn't depend on epsilon ?

Comment: There are examples of topological spaces where sequences converge in the usual sense iff this condition is satisfied iff they are eventually constant.

Answer (score 3):

It means that from $N$, all the terms of the sequence are equal to the limit $\ell$ ! Indeed, forall $n \geqslant N$, you can make $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, which leads to $u_n = \ell$ forall $n \geqslant N$ (with usual notations).